# How can I read the Windows "Virtual Bytes" performance counter, in Java, for a Java process?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, monitoring, performancecounter

Perhaps making use of [jniwrap.jar and winpack.jar](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/) so I don't have to roll my own JNI code, how can I read the "Virtual Bytes" performance counter for a Java service?  The service will read its own performance counter so that it can periodically log how much virtual address space is in use.  Currently, it logs the JMX value "CommittedVirtualMemorySize" returned by the OS JMX MBean, but this only shows the amount of memory that is **committed**, so doesn't really help you understand if you are about to exhaust your virtual address space.

This is for a Java-based server process where sometimes the Java compiler thread exhausts the C Heap, crashing the whole JVM in the process.  My own code is not the culprit -- it's the JVM itself.  But this diagnostic data will help me understand the full virtual address space needs of the service.

Edit:  Since asking this question, I have tried several different things, so far to no avail.  It turns out that winpack.jar allows registry access and there is a registry key `RegistryKey.PERFORMANCE_DATA` that supposedly provides access to performance data via registry-like access, but I always got no keys back.  I found some [sample code](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8393) in VB that used this method to get performance data, and even with that code, I got back no data.  This is on a Win7Pro desktop.  Is this data not available by default?

If I cannot get that method to work, then I think the only other choice is trying to use jniwrap or winpack to somehow execute code in Java equivalent to this C# code:

```
PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter();
PC.CategoryName = "Process";
PC.CounterName = "Virtual Bytes";
PC.InstanceName = "Java#1";
PC.ReadOnly = true;
float VirtualBytes = PC.NextValue();
```

but I can't think of a good way to do this.  Is there anyone familiar either with Jniwrapper/winpack or with getting performance data via the registry who can suggest a way of doing this?

I recognize there's always the possibility of writing an external C# program or WMI script to get this information, but I expect that to be orders of magnitude slower (and more work to implement) than getting direct programmatic access to this information.

Comment: Make a dll in c# and call it from java using java com bridge.

Comment: That may be the easiest solution, since this stuff is so trivial to get at in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [WinPack.jar](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/) library direclty provides this information!  I didn't find any documentation that helped me find this.  Just looking through its API documentation and experimenting, I was able to come up with this code.  Replace `MemoryStatus` with `MemoryInfo` if you're using the latest version of the library:

```
import com.jniwrapper.win32.system.MemoryStatus;

...

private void test() {
  MemoryStatus mStatus = new MemoryStatus();
  System.out.println("TotalVirtual: " + getBytesInMB(mStatus.getTotalVirtual()) + " MB");
  System.out.println("AvailVirtual: " + getBytesInMB(mStatus.getAvailVirtual()) + " MB");
  System.out.println("UsedVirtual:  " + getBytesInMB(mStatus.getTotalVirtual() - mStatus.getAvailVirtual()) + " MB");
}

private long getBytesInMB(final long input) {
  return input / 1024 / 1024;
}
```

this gives me what I am looking for -- the virtual address space usage of the Java process that is running this code.  It is not a general purpose solution, but it may help other people who want to log the same kind of information.